# why my actual UI layout is not same with my designed layout in xib

Tags: ios, sdk

this is what I designed in xib, and it's my expectation also.
[image]

My ViewControlle.h file:

```
@interface DetailHeadViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *slideScrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *smallImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *barBGVImageView;

@end
```

My ViewController.m file （part of the source code)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    slideScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    slideScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    slideScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    UIImageView * page1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"headSection_hot1"]];
    [slideScrollView addSubview:page1];   //Update 3
}
```

the result is this,
[image]

But actually the correct result is this,

[image]

Anyone can help to point out what the problem is?
Thanks in advance

### update (remove bar image)

for easier, I remove bar image in xib and also comment out the relatived code.
Please see the following picture.
[image]

### update 2

IB 
[image]

Comment: have you enabled transparency on the bar image?

Comment: the bar image is transparency. I think the problem is the position of the bar image and small image.

Comment: Could you maybe upload your bottom bar to check it's transparency?Also, what is the background color of your container view?

Comment: it may be that on the right panel of the storyboard, you need to explicitly tell it that the image is transparent (there's a checkbox)

Comment: What do you have your scroll view frame set to?

Comment: @ohr,please see 'update'. I removed bar image. background color is white by default.

Comment: @iBlue, thanks, please see 'update' part. I remove bar image

Comment: @Darren, I didn't set scroll view frame as I set it in xib. I think xib can show what I drew. And before I post, I also set it frame. I did like this [slideScrollView setFrame:[self.view frame]]; but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your scroll view frame is not set correctly. It should probably be set to 0,0,480,320.

It also looks like the transparency isn't set on the BarImageView. Select the BarImageView in the xib, open up the inspector window, click on the 4th tab, set the background color to Clear Color and reduce the alpha.

You may also want to post how your adding the image to the scroll view as that could create issues as well.

---

Update 1:

In the viewDidLoad of your DetailHeadViewController try this:

```
self.scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds;
UIImageView * page1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"headSection_hot1"]];
page1.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.slideScrollView addSubview:page1];
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.view.bounds.size; // Note that the contentSize must be changed
                                                     // from this if you want to scroll.
```

Comment: it's iphone app with retina display. I try to set scroll view's frame, but failed. actually I drew in xib, it should be same with xib, I guess.

Comment: hi @Darren, please see my 'update' part. I remove the bar image. The problem is still there.

Comment: Set the frame in the xib file by selecting it in the xib, opening the inspector window, clicking on the 5th tab at the top of this window and setting x=0,y=0,width=480,height=320. Make sure that the top level view has these same settings.

Comment: for my case the view size is (0,0,320,225), my scrollview size is also (0,0,320,225). I confirm the settings are same. And the image size is 640x450. I do it for retina display. I don't think the problem is here.

Comment: Oh, so the view that you posted only takes up a part of the screen? Try explicitly setting the frame of page1 before adding it to the scroll view -> page1.frame = self.view.bounds.

Comment: yes, it's part of screen. I also did what you said on setting frame before calling the view controller.